# using "git submodule foreach" can you skip a list of submodules?

Tags: linux, git, foreach, git-submodules

lets say I have 10 submoules:

```
module/1
module/2
module/3
module/4
module/5
module/6
module/7
module/8
module/9
module/10
```

where `module/` is the top-level repo.

I want to do `git submodule foreach 'git status'`, but I don't want to do it for submodules 4, 6 and 7.

Is there a way to do that, somthing like :

`git submodule foreach --exclude="4 6 7" 'git status'`

I tried doing it inside the command block using

```
git submodule foreach '
    if [[ $list_of_ignores =~ *"$displayname"* ]] ; then echo ignore; fi
'
```

**update** - removed `--exclude="4 6 7"` that was accidently in there

But I get errors saying `eval [[: not found` - I am assuming this is because it is using /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash? - not sure...

Comment: `git submodule` is still a [shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-submodule.sh). You can see how `cmd_foreach` works, and copy it to your own variant and add features, if you like. Unfortunately most of the work happens in `git-submodule-helper`, which *isn't* a script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the docs say, foreach executes shell commands,

> ```
> foreach [--recursive] <command>
>     Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule. The 
>     command has access to the variables $name, $sm_path, $displaypath, $sha1
>     and $toplevel
> ```

so use the shell:

```
 git submodule foreach 'case $name in 4|6|7) ;; *) git status ;; esac'
```

If the syntax looks strange to you, look up the syntax for bash's `case` statements. The above, if written in a script with line breaks, would be:

```sh
case $name in # $name is available to `submodule foreach`
    4|5|6)
     ;;
    *)     # default "catchall"
     git status 
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: I saw the case method - but I can't pass these arguments into a script via a variable list (e.g. `$list_of_ignores` which contains some list specified by the caller). This is a bit too hard-coded : (  Ca it be done by passing in a variable with the list of submodules to ignore? +1 for the answer so far though : )

Comment: Sure:   `excludes='4|6|7' git submodule foreach 'eval "case \$name in $excludes) ;; *) git status ;; esac"'`

Comment: Two points, I just noticed your `please stop faking evidence` comment. I was not, don't understand why someone would. I just re-ran it and I got exaclt the same error as I mentioned.  Second point - I can't seem to use variables set outside of submodule foreach 'cmd-block'. So your variable `excludes` in your comment seems to evaulate to an empty string.    After re-reading the man page (you pasted) it seems to suggest that we don't get access to external variables.... : (

Comment: Note: I just removed the `--exclude="4 6 7"` part of the thing you c&p'ed. that was mistakenly left in there. So now it will give the error I mentioned - so again, not faking, just mistaken. So my "please stop" to you would be "please stop jumping to conclusions and thinking the worst of people" : )

Comment: So finally figured it out (from the good start point you gave me). The single quotes don't expand the passed in variable so have to use double quotes: `excludes='4|6|7' git submodule foreach "eval \"case \$name in $excludes) ;; *) git status ;; esac\""`.  Even though I don't agree with being called a faker, the qusetion was non-the-less answered well, so selecting as the answer.

Comment: The shell is the one that comes with ubuntu 18.04, pretty decent in my view. You're example just plain does not work. Using single quote does not expand the variables, you need to use double quote like I showed you : )    .I did not add "spurious text". How it can't be intentional is that - if you look at the code just before my "faked" code you will see the exact same text that I removed - its called a copy/paste error, I just don't think its very fair to accuse someone of faking because they make a mistake.  I imagine the words you where looking for are: "yeah, my bad... sorry mate"

Comment: Now, how do you do it in Windows (PowerShell)?

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of what [code_fodder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2298137/code-fodder) and [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) have said (adding one backlash helped the command to run properly and it's also good to add `--recursive` flag), the following command helps exclude different submodules, e.g. 4, 5 and 6 and run `git status` for every nested submodule:

```
excludes='4|6|7' git submodule foreach --recursive "eval \"case \$name in \$excludes) ;; *) git status ;; esac\""
```

Comment: What about in Windows PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

This might probably be a terrible workaround but it works for my specific case.

`git submodule foreach --recursive` will only iterate over the existing folder (non-recursive as well), so I usually just delete the folders to skip **(assuring firstly that everything is committed/stashed!)**.

So in case of the following sub-module structure:

```
tree
.
├── 1
├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   └── 4
├── 5
│   ├── 6
│   │   ├── 7
│   └── 8
└── 9
```

If I want to execute `foo` command on every submodule except `5` and children I just delete the `5` folder:

```
rm -rf 5
git submodule --recursive foo             # 5, 6, 7, 8 won't be touched.
git submodule --update --init --recursive # Restore the removed folders.
```

Comment: This is a pretty crazy idea